# How can I detect red particles on an image using python opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, colors

my job is to detect and get the size of red particles from image. I tried simple blob detections, but works bad with colour filter and extracting values of red using the HSV but I got poor results because the image has small resolution (I work on Rasperry Pi using a webcam).

Here is a sample picture: 
[image]

Comment: It's hard to imagine, without some sample images :(

Comment: please post a sample picture, and the code you tried maybe

Comment: I added a sample picture in the post. Thanks for help:)

Comment: FYI, 1080 x 1920 is **not** small resolution.  Perhaps to someone crazy about HD, but definitely not in image processing.  Also, colour segmentation has nothing to do with resolution.  It has everything to do about the distribution of colours.  Segmentation in that aspect is independent of the size of your image.

Answer (score 3):

Using the HSV colour space is perfectly fine.  If you show the hue and saturation components of the image, you'll see that the red particles have a relatively large hue with a small saturation.

BTW, your image is rather large in resolution.  I'm going to downsample for the purposes of fitting the images into the post as well as minimizing processing time.  First let's load in your image, resize it down to 25% resolution, then extract out the HSV components:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('sample.png')
im_resize = cv2.resize(im, None, None, 0.25, 0.25)
out = cv2.cvtColor(im_resize, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
stacked = np.hstack([out[...,0], out[...,1]])
cv2.imshow("Hue & Saturation", stacked) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm also stacking the hue and saturation channels together into a single image so we can see what it looks like and displaying this to the screen.

We get this image:

[image: hue and saturation]

The combination of a relatively large hue component with a low saturation component is unique in comparison to the rest of the image.  Let's do some simple thresholding to extract out those components where we look for areas that have a hue component that is greater than one threshold and a saturation component that is smaller than another threshold:

```
hue_thresh = 100
saturation_thresh = 32

thresh = np.logical_and(out[...,0] > hue_thresh, out[...,1] < saturation_thresh)

cv2.imshow("Thresholded", 255*(thresh.astype(np.uint8)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I set some tuned thresholds, then use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to combine both conditions together.  Because the image is now of type `bool` and to display images, they should be an unsigned or floating-point type, we convert the image to `uint8` then multiply by 255.

We now get this image:

[image: thresholded]

As you can see, we extract out the portions that are a reddish hue that is not common with the background.  The thresholds will also need to be played around with, but it's fine for this particular example.